# position of multiple strings in an arrray

Tags: java, android

I try to get multiple positions of a string in a string array, I know how to get one, but it just give me one position, not all of them.

```
String Color[] = "Red","Blue","Green","Red","White","Orange","Green","White","Yellow";
int index = Arrays.asList(Color).indexOf("Red");
```

so the result would be 0,
but as a result I want 0 and 3.

and I don't know how to get those results, maybe in a int array or so, but i don't know how to do it properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For one you know the size of red, so you can just add the length of red to the result. Second, I am not sure this code will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your Color array isn't created the right way. Here is a working example what you want.

```
String colors[] = { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "White", "Orange",
                "Green", "White", "Yellow" };
String lookingForColor = "Red";

List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    if (colors[i].equals(lookingForColor)) {
        indexes.add(i);
        Log.i("YOURTAG", "item match at: " + i);
    }
}
```

indexes contains 0 and 3

Comment: Thanks!
and that colors wasn't created the right way is because I wanted to typ it quickly. It was just a typo.